# How can I script a Docker command into a 'single word' binary? Using bash script?

Tags: bash, docker, scripting, sh, nmap

When I install something like nmap(even from APT), I cant get it to execute correctly, so I like to go the container route. Instead of typing:

`docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap -A -T4 scanme.nmap.org`

I figured maybe I could script it out, but nothing i've learned or found on google, youtube, etc, has helped so far... Can somebody lend a hand? I need to know how to get Bash to execute a command with args:

execute like:

`./nmap.sh -A -T4 -Pn x.x.x.x`

`#!/bin/bash`

`echo docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap $1 $2 $3 $4 $5`

but how to get bash to run this instead of just echo I dont know. Thanks ahead!

Comment: Like using a bash function (or even an alias)? I'm not sure I understand correctly, but you could just put a function in your `.bashrc` that has the command in it, and then just call the function when you need it.

Comment: Have you tried without echo? like `docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 `, if so what is the error you are getting.

Comment: I'll lyk soon, im gonna try and see what happens, I never tried cuz I knew the "echo would just ... echo lol"

Comment: (You don't need to edit your question to include "solved" in the title; if the question has an accepted answer that's visible in many places in Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Cool thanks David, I see it all the time on other forums so I figured id be like everybody else lol

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: create an alias, create a script.

### With an alias

The command you write is replaced with the value of the alias, so

```bash
alias nmap="docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap"

nmap -A -T4 -Pn x.x.x.x
# executes docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap -A -T4 -Pn x.x.x.x
```

Aliases are not persistent so you will have to store it in some bash config (generally `~/.bashrc`).

### With a script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -Eeuo pipefail

docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap "$@"
```

`"$@"` will forward all the arguments provided to the script directly to the command. The quotes are important, if you call your script with quoted values like `./nmap "something with spaces"`, that's one argument, it needs to be kept as one argument.

### Bonus: With a function

Just like the script, you need to forward arguments when writing functions, just like aliases, they are not persistent so you have to store them in bash config:

```bash
nmap() {
  docker run --rm -it instrumentisto/nmap "$@"
}
```

Comment: This is AWESOME! I'm very new so im still learning but this just great! thanks guys, I edited my .bashrc and added the docker command to it and it worked, this has inspired me to run all of my stuff now like that through Docker! and yeah I mean everything, because man its waaay faster, and not to mention automatically updates to whatever the latest image is. thanks again fellas

Comment: BTW can I not use $* to call all arguments down ?? I literally just saw it in a video I think?? so ima give that a shot too! why not right

Comment: `$*` should be avoided in  favor of `"$@"`. The original Bourne shell initially lacked the latter, and you still see help materials and tutorials which erroneously promote the original convention from 1979. But it should generally be avoided; `$*` irrevocably loses escaping and quoting of shell metacharacters in the user's arguments. http://shellcheck.net/ can often tell you "why not right?"